# POSIX semaphores are not initialized and process aborts when trying to post to semaphore: The futex facility returned an unexpected error code

Tags: c, posix, semaphore, shared-memory, glibc

I am using 2 POSIX semaphores to signal between processes when reads and writes to shared memory are OK. However, when I try to post or wait on the semaphore, I get the below error:

```
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.
```

I believe this means I am initializing the semaphore incorrectly, or I have some sort of synchronization bug.

In my design, either process (P1 or P2) can create the semaphore, depending on what code executes first. Both use the same means of opening the read and write semaphores.

```
sem_t *readsem = NULL;
sem_t *writesem = NULL;

if ((readsem = sem_open("/readsem", O_CREAT, 0777, 0)) == SEM_FAILED) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if ((writesem = sem_open("/writesem", O_CREAT, 0777, 0)) == SEM_FAILED) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

When I want to post or read I simply just use the API:

```
sem_post(readsem);
sem_wait(writesem);
```

When I tried to debug by using sem_getvalue(readsem) to inspect the value, The value is not 0 or 1 as expected. Instead it seems that it is just junk memory value 2057840963. I have tried writing out how my synchronization works, but I am still not sure what the problem is, nor how to debug semaphores or the futex error.

Comment: You will have to post a reproducer for this. It could be caused by memory corruption somewhere else in your program. Have you tried running valgrind?

Comment: It's impossible to tell where the problem is without looking at the source code. You should find a way to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: As an hint, [looking at the glibc source code](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/nptl/futex-internal.h.html#futex_fatal_error), one can see that the function that produces that error string is called `futex_fatal_error()`, and is only called from 7 places (hover over the name with the mouse to see the usages). One could narrow the problem down by looking at where it is called and the function that calls it.

Comment: Ok, I will work on a minimum reproducible example. I suppose now is the time to learn valgrind

Comment: I suspect this is because I am repeatedly calling sem_open on  the semaphore in threads.